# In Python, why do I get an 'undefined local variable' error for counters but not for lists?

Tags: python

If I alter a variable declared at the top of the file/module from within a method (no classes involved), it only works in the case of lists/containers, but not if my variable was a simple counter. See the following code for example:

```
counter = 0
counterList = []

def incrementCounter():
    counter += 1

def addToList():
    counterList.append(1)

# works:
addToList()

# doesn't work:
incrementCounter()    

print counterList, counter
```

What is the reason for this differing behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
def incrementCounter():
    global counter
    counter += 1
```

The assignment to `counter` inside `incrementCounter()` otherwise implicitely makes `counter` local to that function.

The line `counter += 1` does not actually change the integer object `counter` points to -- integers are immutable in Python.  The line is rather equivalent to

```
counter = counter + 1
```

thus creating a new integer object and making the name `counter` point to that new integer object.  When compiling the function, Python detects the assignment to `counter` and assumes the name `counter` to be local to the function *even before the assignment*.  When the above line gets executed, the right hand side is evaluated.  Python tries to look up the name `counter` in the local namespace, since it assumes `counter` to be local.  There is no such name in the local namespace though, hence the error message.

Answer (score 3):

The actual reason is that you are not changing the value of the list by appending to it.  If you increment counter, you are changing the value, which is not allowed, unless you declare it as `global`.